# adding more textviews for every xml tag on android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, sax

i'm pretty new to android programming and i'm try to read an xml file. that all works fine, and i can see in the logCat that he is receiving all the data but the app only shows 5 of the tag from the xml file. so i was wondering if i could add some sort of string that will add a new textView/listView or what ever view i need.

Comment: long story short - use `ListView`

Comment: the is what is was trying but, i won't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good Android API guide on this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html